# Using javascript hide()/show() in vb.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, vb.net

I am creating a website using vb.net. What I want to do is not have multiple forms just multiple 's on the page and hide/show them on the button click so there will be no change in the actual url, just display of the page.
So I am using vb.net and javascript to achieve that.

my vb.aspx page :

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--

    function show_ata() {
        $('#dmi').hide();
        $('#ata').show("slow");

    }
    function back() {
        $('#ata').hide();
        $('#dmi').show("slow");
    }

// -->
    </script>
    </asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="BodyContent" runat="server">
 <div id="ata" runat="server" >
<p>ATA</p>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button1" OnClientClick="return back()" Text="Back to DMI" CausesValidation="false" />
</div>
<div id="dmi" runat="server">
<p>DMI</p>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnatadetails" OnClientClick="return show_ata()" Text="Go to ATA" CausesValidation="false" />
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

So that is my code, I have some code on .aspx.vb page too, but it is only to do with checking if user is logged in, and has nothing to do with page display so I will not post it here.

**MY PROBLEM**
My problem is that for some reason button on click action hides given div only for 1 sec and then shows it again, my intend was to hide it and stay hidden.

Any ideas what am i doing wrong?

**SOLUTION**
Some of you guys suggested that I should wrap my javascript code in document ready function, which is probably correct but does not solve my issue.
Solution is either write vb code for button click like this:

```
Private Sub btnatadetails_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnatadetails.Click
        dmi.Visible = False
        ata.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Or not to use `ASP:Button` and use html button `<input type=button>` because `asp:button` runs on server and on every click page will reload and come back to its original state.

Thanks for help guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION 
Some of you guys suggested that I should wrap my javascript code in document ready function, which is probably correct but does not solve my issue. Solution is either write vb code for button click like this:

```
Private Sub btnatadetails_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnatadetails.Click
    dmi.Visible = False
    ata.Visible = True
```

End Sub
Or not to use ASP:Button and use html button because asp:button runs on server and on every click page will reload and come back to its original state.

Thanks for help guys.

Answer (score 1):

> click action hides given div only for 1 sec and then shows it again

Because it is calling before document is ready and after ready it's showing it's original.

**Solution:**
Wrap your code inside ready handler:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//your code here
});
```

Comment: I have done that and now it does not hide it at all, I have also noticed that my page reloads after button click

Comment: I have added a property to my button :  UseSubmitBehavior="false" and now I get an error in developer tools console: Uncaught ReferenceError: show_ata is not defined

Comment: I have updated the main post with the solution, thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

you need simply add $(document).ready(function(){ ... } to use jquery

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 <!--
$(document).ready(function(){
 function show_ata() {
     $('#dmi').hide();
     $('#ata').show("slow");

 }
 function back() {
     $('#ata').hide();
     $('#dmi').show("slow");
 }
}
// -->
</script>
```

Comment: I have done that and now it does not hide it at all, I have also noticed that my page reloads after button click, and there is no other function assigned to it other than this javascript one

Comment: I have added a property to my button :  UseSubmitBehavior="false" and now I get an error in developer tools console: Uncaught ReferenceError: show_ata is not defined

Comment: I have updated the main post with the solution, thanks for help